# How to automatically add string, e.g., -dev, to NuGet packages generated by DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our DevOps Pipeline has versioningScheme set to off in the nuget pack command ([options for that are documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops)), and we're using the AssemblyVersion attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs file to specify NuGet package versions. E.g.,:

```cs
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.9.14")]
```

We have a DevOps Pipeline setup that, when we merge code into our Git "develop" branch, will automatically perform a Debug build and publish to our private NuGet repository. The NuGet package version will match the AssemblyVersion attribute's value.

We have another DevOps pipeline that will do the same for the Master branch, but the build will be in Release mode.

We would like to have the Pipeline for the "develop" branch automatically append a string, e.g., "-beta" or "-dev", so that we can easily distinguish our pre-release builds, that are built in Debug mode, from the release builds. I've reviewed the YAML for our pipeline and I have been unable to figure out how to do that when you're using the AssemblyVersion (or AssemblyInformationalVersion) attribute. Is this possible? Or would we need to switch to a different technique for specifying versions?

YAML for our current Pipeline is below:

```yaml
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: 'DataAccessLayer/DataAccessLayer.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'off'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: '2ba68ed5-dcd7-40e3-8b6b-06972c41ec5e'
```

Comment: Agree with Simon Ness. How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Simon Ness's solution will work for us. Thank you for checking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`versioningScheme: 'off'` in the pack step is the issue, it means there is no way to override the package version passed to the nuget pack command.

Rather than setting the version number explicitly in the assembly info file, an alternative solution is to just specify the major minor version and let Azure Devops calculate the next patch version with a [counter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter) expression, then setting the build number to major.minor.path:

```
variables:
  majorMinor: 1.10
  patch: $[counter(variables['majorMinor'])]

steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'echo patch (debug)'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: echo $(patch)

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'update build number to major.minor.patch'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        if ("$(Build.SourceBranchName)" -eq "master") {
          echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(majorMinor).$(patch)"
        } else {
          echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(majorMinor).$(patch)-alpha"
        }
```

You can then make use of the `BUILD_BUILDNUMBER` environment variable in your nuget pack step:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: 'DataAccessLayer/DataAccessLayer.csproj'
    versioningScheme: byEnvVar
    versionEnvVar: BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
```

Comment: How is `BUILD_BUILDNUMBER` getting setting in your example?

Comment: And what is the purpose of the `jobs: - job: build` element? I don't have that in my YAML and I'm unclear why it is needed?

Comment: @josh the echo "##vso" command, see https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

Comment: Stages and jobs can be introduced for multi-stage pipelines:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/azure-devops-pipelines-multi-stage-pipelines-and-yaml-for-continuous-delivery/

yaml schema: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pipeline

Comment: But you're right, they're not a requirement for your pipeline, so I've reworked the example.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick for me, and it will suit us. But I am curious--is there a way to observe the major.minor values specified in the AssemblyVersion attribute, and use the "patch" (or build) number for the third number?

Comment: Also, where can I read about this syntax/command: `patch: $[counter(variables['majorMinor'])]`. Looks like $[counter()] is a function that takes an input and will generate an output that increments by one every time it's called, and it will remember it's state (i.e., the counter's prior value) across multiple jobs? What about across multiple pipelines?

Comment: @josh you're welcome.  Updated the answer re the counter.  You could write some powershell to grab the AssemblyVersion but I'd be tempted to set it to 0.0.0 to avoid confusion.

Comment: One alternative method I've thought about is to simply go with the default build number format and add "-alpha" or "-develop" to to the version. I tried this with `echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(build.updatebuildnumber)-develop` but it fails with an error that it contains invalid characters. I'm not really clear on how this assignment is supposed to work as there is no `=` that clearly tells me where what is used to calculate the new value? Could you clarify how this is working, and also how you would go with the default build number and just append "-develop"?

Comment: The default build number format is not suitable as a nuget package version, here's more info on that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml